# Does it make sense to add validations for models when they are not exposed by routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does it make sense to add model level validations, e.g:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

When it's a resource that it's not exposed by a route?

A good friend of mine told me that I should always add validations for columns that can't be null in the database. E.g:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site, null: false
      t.string :title, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In that case I should have the following validations:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :site_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Now, posts can only be created through the parent:

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post
  # ...
end
```

But when I try to create a post through the site it will fail with:

```
{
    "post.site_id": [
        "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

Should or Shouldn't I add the validations? It seems a bit odd to add validations for models that can't be touched directly through a route.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using nested attributes to update the value?

Comment: Depends. Having a validation like this helps with spec-ing and being more explicit what you want to do. This is subject to preference, some people just disable `belongs_to_required_by_default`. Maybe this will answer some of your concerns: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/validation-database-constraint-or-both

Comment: Model level validations leads to very weird situations when your app grows. Read about form objects and form level validations

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to add validations for models when they are not
>   exposed by routes?

#### Yes.

Not every model in a Rails application will actually correspond to a route and its own controller. Models can represent more than just RESTful resources (although that's what they are used for 99% of time.

Also not having a route does not mean that the model does not deal with user input. When you use nested attributes you are still taking input from the user.

#### But thats not really relevant here.

Usually when defining nested resources you do it like this:

```
resources :sites do
  resources :posts
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before :action_set_site

  # POST /sites/1/posts
  def create
    @post = @site.posts.new(post_params)
    # ...
  end

  private
  def set_site
    @site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
  end
end
```

In this case it does not matter if there is a validation on Post since `Site.find(params[:site_id])` will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error if the parameter is not present or does not correspond to a record. Rails catches this exception and returns a `404 - Not Found` response which is the correct response in this case. If the client tries to create a resource on an endpoint that does not exist you SHOULD NOT return `422 - Bad Entity`.

You also seem to have completely misunderstood what nested attributes should be used for. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is a dirty hack that's really useful if you have to mosh the creation/update of multiple resources into a single form / request. In this case if you want to let the user create a post and site and the same time. In that case the validation is also irrelevant as nested attributes by design will nest the post in a site.

It should NOT be used just because one resource can only exist in the context of another. That's what nested routes are for.

Comment: In my question I used a bad example. In the real app I'm using nested attributes to create entities that should only exist together. E.g: one visitor has many pageviews, but one pageview can't and shouldn't exist without a visitor. I'm using the visitor controller to create pageviews in this case, and I can't take the risky of the visitor not existing since the pageview is registered when the user leaves the page, makes sense?

Comment: In the case above, I can't state in the pageview model `validates :visitor_id, presence: true`

Answer (score -1):

When using nested attributes, the `site_id` is sometimes not yet known when saving the site + post. You have to tell rails that the associations are related, like this

```
class Site 
  has_many :posts

class Post 
  belongs_to :site, inverse_of: :posts
```

Please note that, since rails 5, adding a `belongs_to` adds a validation in itself. One can overrule this by writing

```
  belongs_to :site, optional: true
```

When using nested attributes you will have to remove the `validates :site_id, presence: true` validation, because the `site_id` is not yet known when checking the validations. The validations (at rails level) are checked before the site + post is saved (and thus, before an id is assigned).

The database constraint is definitely valuable imho. Adding validations on rails level is indeed especially needed/adviced to trap errors in a more user-friendly way when entering forms (in other words: if they get created/edited with user-generated data). So it does not matter which route exposes them, but if there is a page containing a form to create/edit them.

Comment: I had to be clearer: in the case of nested attributes you will have to remove the `site_id` validation, because it is not yet known when checking the validations. The validations (at rails level) are checked before the site + post is saved (and thus, before an id is assigned).